# Code to clear all plots in RStudio

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

I have code to clear the workspace: `rm(list=ls())` and code to clear the console: `cat("\014")`

Is there code to clear all plots from Rstudio?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`dev.off()` closes the current graphical device.  This clears all of the plots for me in RStudio as long as I don't have a different graphical device open at the moment.  If you do have other graphical devices open then you can use `dev.list()` to figure out which graphical device is RStudio's.  The following *should* do that but I haven't tested it thoroughly.

```
dev.off(dev.list()["RStudioGD"])
```

But if you aren't doing anything else then just using `dev.off()` should take care of it.

Comment: A caveat about the accepted answer. This works without a hitch in RStudio's console, but we see strange results when using it in a script (for instance, along with the other items OP mentioned, to scrub the environment each time a particular script is run). After a second run, you can't click backwards through a list of generated plots without failures & warnings about not being able to open connections or find temp files; it seems like this doesn't flush the "plots" history when run from script?

Comment: (Mac OSX Yosemite & Windows 7, RStudio 0.99.486)

Comment: @mojoronomous Works fine for me. Running RStudio 0.99.484 on Ubuntu.

Comment: This didn't help when working on a R markdown in RStudio (v 1.1.463, Linux x86_64). plots were still resident. `Run` -> `Restart R and clear output` did the trick.

Answer (score 46):

`dev.off()` only works in an interactive session. If you're interested in implementing such behavior in a script, you should use

```
graphics.off()
```

instead.

Comment: This does not seem to be an improvement. In a script both graphics.off() and dev.off() lead here to exactly the same problems/errors as mojoronomous has described.   (RStudio 1.0.44, R 3.3.2)

Comment: Excellent solution! This fixed an empty square plot in my graphics. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

To prevent error message in case there are no plots to clear:

```
if(!is.null(dev.list())) dev.off()
```

Comment: Although this solution works, it results in an error when cycling through the plots during the second run. Bug reported here: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3117

Answer (score 7):

I usually use

```
while (dev.cur()>1) dev.off()
```

and since I use RGL a lot, I often add:

```
while (rgl.cur()) rgl.close()
```

Answer (score 6):

I have gone for this which seems to work without reporting any errors:

```
# Clear all plots
try(dev.off(dev.list()["RStudioGD"]),silent=TRUE)
try(dev.off(),silent=TRUE)
```

I merged the instructions from the other answers with an answer on error handling [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111956/suppress-error-message-in-r):