# Suppressing error message for hclust in knitr/Rmarkdown and assign output to variable

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to cluster my data using `hclust` and print to a html using Rmarkdown.

When I call `hclust` from the console or in an .Rmd, the clustering occurs perfectly exactly as I want it. But additionally, I receive the error message:

```
must have n >= 2 objects to cluster
```

I can force knitr to continue processing using `error=TRUE`, but the error is there and the value not assigned.

```
tree = hclust(dist(t(sample_matrix), method = "euclidean"), method = "complete")
```

I want to process object `tree` further
I have also tried "fixing" the error by using `try(...,silent=TRUE)`. It works as long as I don't need to assign the returned value.
Also `tryCatch` doesn't seem to help with this (correct me if I'm wrong).

How can I suppress this error message in my Rmarkdown?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111956/suppress-error-message-in-r) could be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I tried `tryCatch` and it appears to work.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Roman Luštrik"
date: "23. november 2015"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
x <- tryCatch(simpleError("eror mesiđ"), error = function(e) e)
```

```{r}
plot(runif(100), runif(100))
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Roman Luštrik, this is not exactly what's the problem. The function call ends with error, but I need to use further on the value returned by this function. In console everything works seamlessly.

Comment: @Jelena-bioinf you can have `tryCatch` return anything you want (other than the true result as if no error had occurred, obviously).