# Ignore/suppress error while joining on empty dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dynamic automatic process where I pick up files, process them and `left_join` them together.

I don't always get all the files so sometimes my RHS `left_join` table is empty which consequently throws the error

> Error: Not compatible with STRSXP: [type=NULL].

Consider following example

```r
library(dplyr)
df <-structure(list(id = c(1, 2), var = c("a", "b")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

df2 <- structure(list(), class = "data.frame", row.names = integer(0))

df %>% 
  left_join(df2, by=('id'))
```

Is there a simple way to ignore/suppress the error for the join if the RHS table is empty?

Thanks

Comment: You can check `?possibly` or `?safely` from `purrr` or  `tryCatch` from `base R`

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111956/suppress-error-message-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments I came up with following simple approach which might help someone else in the future having a similar problem.

```r
df %>% {
  tryCatch(left_join(.,df2, by = ('id')),
           error=function(e) .)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since if..else doesn't play well in piped statements, I would make a custom function to just return the (presumed) non-blank data frame. You may want to add a third condition if both are blank, but this should get you started:

```
left_join_if_exists = function(d1, d2, by) {
  if (0 %in% dim(d1)) {
    message("Warning: First data frame is empty")
    return(d2)
  } else if (0 %in% dim(d2)) {
    message("Warning: Second data frame is empty")
    return(d1)
  } else{
    return( left_join(d1,d2,by = by) )
  }
}

df %>% 
  left_join_if_exists( ., df2, by=c('id'))
```