# Is it possible to not printing error messages when knitting an RMarkdown messages?

Tags: r, error-handling, r-markdown, knitr

I have the next code:

```r
ks.test(NA, "pnorm")
```

It throws an error. I have it inside the `try` function to allow that error (in fact, I do not have `NA` in such a code, but a changing data). I hoped that in an RMarkdown document, writing `error=FALSE` would not print the error `not enough 'x' data` but I have found that this is not the expected behaviour: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/opts-error.html

Is there a way to not printing the error message?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Did you try `try(ks.test(NA, "pnorm"), silent=TRUE)` ? (Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111956/suppress-error-message-in-r)

Comment: If you have it inside a `try` command, the error becomes a warning, so you can use the chunk option `warning = FALSE`.