# How to suppress error messages from a function?

Tags: r

```
R> data.frame(x=1, y=1)
  x y
1 1 1
R> suppressWarnings(rq(y~x, data=data.frame(x=1, y=1)[-1, , drop=F]))
Error in rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau, ...) : Singular design matrix
R> suppressMessages(rq(y~x, data=data.frame(x=1, y=1)[-1, , drop=F]))
Error in rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau, ...) : Singular design matrix
```

I want to suppress error messages above. But the two functions that I tried did not work. Is there a way to suppress error messages like this?

Comment: Posts to SO should be reproducible by others.  In particular all inputs and library statements should be shown.  See the guidance at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.

Comment: Maybe add `library(quantreg)` to be reproducible.

Comment: Have also a look at [Suppress error message in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19111956/10488504).

Answer (score 5):

Wrap the offending statement with `try(...)` using `silent=TRUE`:

```
stop(TRUE)
## Error: TRUE

# this results in no displayed error message
try(stop(TRUE), silent = TRUE)
```